# How to make variables be accessible from scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, variable

In Ubuntu 16.04 I executed a script (script 1) which by itself executes two other scripts (script 2 and script 3).

Script 3 contains a variable substitution (`${x}`) for a variable already declared in script 2 (`x=y`).

Of course, before executing script 3, I made sure to `source` script 2, so that future variable substitution would be allowed in script 3 or otherwise.

---

The problem is that when I execute script 3 (through script 1), the variable substitution fails and the result is imperfect, but in a manual execution it succeeds.

---

Why does the variable substitution fails when script 3 is executed through script 1, but succeeds in manual execution, and how to make sure it will indeed take place?

If `sourcing` of script 2 isn't enough, well, I have no idea what is.

Comment: I'm confused. If the scripts are short, please post them as an edit to your question. Please also post your keystroke sequences for what you describe as 'manual' and 'scriptural'. Also, please edit your question to change your use of the term 'scriptural' - it is a word, but is an adjective meaning "of, from, or relating to the Bible" ... not that there's anything wrong with that ... but I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: I'm also confused. Please create short scripts that are _minimal working examples_.

Comment: Please provide a [complete MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with code of the three scripts so we can make tests, thanks.

Comment: Is what you're doing the equivalent of `source script2; ./script3`? If so, you can `export` your variable: `export x=y`, in script2.

Comment: @user1404316 sorry, it is the Edge "typo fixer" that replaced "scriptual" to "scriptural", now fixed. I also edited in great detail.

Comment: Maybe instead of 'scriptually' you mean 'programmatically', defined by wiktionary as " Through program code, rather than through a user interface."

Comment: 'By "scriptural execution" I mean to a state when one script executes another script; That is to be distinguished from "manual execution" when a human user executes a script.' Distinguished how? Post what you're actually doing, please, instead of describing it using made-up words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue, and has absolutely nothing to do with whether a script is executed manually from the command line, or executed by another script.

**Shell variables that are not exported to the environment are not visible to child processes (including child shells)**

If you're sourcing `script2` inside `script3`, then `script3` will see all the variables defined in `script2` because it all happens inside the scope of `script3`.   It's pretty much the same if you source both `script2` and `script3` inside `script1` (but in this case, everything happens inside the scope of `script1`)

If, however, you're sourcing `script2` inside `script1` and then executing (**not** sourcing) `script3` from `script1`, then `script3` will only see variables defined or changed in `script2` if they happen to be exported.

It doesn't really matter when or where the variables are exported, as long as it happens **before** `script3` is executed.  The variables can be exported in `script1` or in `script2`, or even in the parent shell (or its .profile/.bashrc/etc) that executed `script1` to begin with.